# Долгий commit solr'а

Tags: java, solr

Использую версию 3.5, commit делается от 60 до 180 секунд. На версии 1.4 (2.9) таких проблем не было. При commit передаются 2 флага `waitFlush` и `waitSearch`. Если их поставить `false, false`, то commit'иться быстро. Ну у меня вопрос: чего мне в этом случае опасаться? Что меняется от того, что там стоят `false, false`?

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с первой части вопроса. commit долго делается из-за удалений. При индексации - лучше ничего не удалять, при проектировании схемы хранения нужно учитывать это.

Вторая часть почему если waitFlush и waitSearch передавать false - то commit быстрый. 
waitFlush - true (по умолчанию) - дождаться записи результата на диск. лучше дожидаться, он идет не долго и он очень важен.

waitSearch - true (по умолчанию) - дождаться окончания работы все поисковиков

**если было удаление** и waitSearch == true, то происходит ожидание закрытие поисковиков, и если поиск идет не переставая (много пользователей, постоянно что то ищется) - то commit вообще не пройдет. 
**если было удаление** и waitSearch == false, то начинают создаваться новые поисковики, что приводит к утечки памяти.Более того по умолчанию - можно создавать только 4 поисковика. Симптом этого, в логах появляется сообщения вида:

INFO: [] PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2

причем номер постоянно растет

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно задать softCommit == true (по умолчанию false). Отложенный коммит.

В нашей системе это ускорило commit c 400ms до 10ms.

Но этого не стоит делать, если мы что-то добавляем в solr индекс и тут же пытаемся по нему искать.